# Compute the Normalized Bracket Polynomial of a Knot, $K$

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

Compute the normalized bracket polynomial 
$$(-A^3)^{-w(D)}\langle D \rangle$$
of the following knot diagram $D$ where $w(D)$ is the writhe of $D$.

[image: Knot Diagram]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I will give three methods of computing the normalized Kauffman bracket polynomial.

**Method 1: Look it up.** The pictured diagram is the mirror of the [$5_2$ knot](http://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/diagram_display/diagram_display_5_2.html) in Rolfsen's tables. The pictured diagram has writhe $w(D)=-5$, and its Jones polynomial (found from [KnotInfo](http://www.indiana.edu/~knotinfo/results.php?searchmode=0&category%5B%5D=%3C%3D6&name=%3D1&jones_polynomial=%3D1&diagram=%3D1) by replacing $t$ with $t^{-1}$ in $V_{5_2}(t)$) is
$$V_{\overline{5_2}}(t) =  t^{-1}-t^{-2}+ 2t^{-3}-t^{-4}+ t^{-5}-t^{-6}.$$
Using the equality
$$V_L(t) = (-A^3)^{-w(D)}\langle D \rangle |_{A=t^{-1/4}},$$
we obtain 
$$(-A^3)^{-w(D)}\langle D \rangle = A^{4} -A^{8} + 2A^{12} - A^{16} +A^{20} - A^{24}.$$

**Method 2: Evaluate the Kauffman bracket.** Since there are five crossings, there are $2^5=32$ Kauffman states. For each state $s$, let $\alpha(s), \beta(s)$, and $|s|$ denote the number of $A$-resolutions in $s$, the number of $B$-resolutions in $s$ and the number of components of $s$ respectively. Then
$$\langle D \rangle = \sum_{s} A^{\alpha(s)-\beta(s)}(-A^2-A^{-2})^{|s|-1}.$$
It is probably best to do this computation with a computer (as in this previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488551/what-is-the-bracket-polynomial-w-of-the-whitehead-link-w) you asked). The end result of such a computation is
$$\langle D \rangle = -A^{-11}+A^{-7}-2A^{-3}+A-A^{5}+A^{9}.$$
Normalizing by $(-A^3)^{-w(D)}=-A^{15}$, we obtain the same answer as in Method 1:
$$(-A^3)^{-w(D)}\langle D \rangle = A^{4} -A^{8} + 2A^{12} - A^{16} +A^{20} - A^{24}.$$

**Method 3. Resolve to twisted unknots.**
The idea here is to only resolve crossings until the diagram becomes a twisted unknot, that is, a diagram of the unknot that can be transformed into the crossing-less diagram using only Reidemeister one moves. Reidemeister one moves change the Kauffman bracket as shown below:
[image]

Thus we can use the above rules to compute the Kauffman bracket of any twisted unknot. Specifically, for a twisted unknot $T$ of writhe $w(T)$, we have
$$\langle T \rangle =(-A^3)^{w(D)}.$$
Start by taking a resolution tree of the diagram $D$, stopping at a leaf whenever one has a twisted unknot, as below.
[image]
It remains to compute $\langle T_i \rangle$ for each twisted unknot, and then to put everything together. We have
\begin{align*}
\langle T_1 \rangle = & \; A^6,\\
\langle T_2 \rangle = &\; 1,\\
\langle T_3 \rangle = &\; -A^{-3},\\
\langle T_4 \rangle = &\; -A^3,\\
\langle T_5 \rangle = &\; -A^{-3},\\
\langle T_6 \rangle = &\; A^{-6},~\text{and}\\
\langle T_7 \rangle = &\; -A^{-9}.
\end{align*}

The path from the original diagram $D$ to each leaf $T_i$ is labeled with $A$'s and $B$'s. Multiply by $A$ for each $A$-label and $A^{-1}$ for each $B$-label. Then add everything together to get $\langle D \rangle$. We have
\begin{align*}
\langle D \rangle = & \; A^3\langle T_1 \rangle + A\langle T_2 \rangle + \langle T_3 \rangle + A^2\langle T_4 \rangle + \langle T_5 \rangle + A^{-1}\langle T_6 \rangle + A^{-2}\langle T_7\rangle\\
= &\; -A^{-11}+A^{-7}-2A^{-3}+A-A^{5}+A^{9}.
\end{align*}
Again we normalize by multiplying by $(-A^3)^{-w(D)}=-A^{15}$ to obtain 
$$(-A^3)^{-w(D)}\langle D \rangle = A^{4} -A^{8} + 2A^{12} - A^{16} +A^{20} - A^{24}.$$